# i am getting error while running the code

Tags: c++, vector

This is Leetcode 200.The question statement is:
Given a 2d grid map of '1's (land) and '0's (water), count the number of islands. An island is surrounded by water and is formed by connecting adjacent lands horizontally or vertically. You may assume all four edges of the grid are all surrounded by water.

```
11110
11010
11000
00000
```

Output: 1

while trying to solve this i am getting the error
**reference binding to null pointer of type 'std::vector >' (stl_vector.h)**

I was getting correct answer for some inputs but overall when i submit it i am getting above error.i would appreciate if anyone can help me with this.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int numIslands(vector<vector<char>>& grid) {
        int count=0;
        int n=grid.size();
        int m=grid[0].size();
        if(grid.size()==0 || grid[0].size()==0)
            return 0;
        bool left,right,top,bottum;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<m;j++)
            {
                   if(grid[i][j]=='1')
                   {
                       count++;
                       BFS(grid,i,j);
                   }
            }
        return count;
}
   void BFS(vector< vector <char> >& grids,int i,int j)
   {
       if(i<0 || j<0 || i>=grids.size() || j>=grids[0].size() || grids[i][j]=='0')
           return ;
       grids[i][j]='0';
       BFS(grids,i+1,j);
       BFS(grids,i,j+1);
       BFS(grids,i-1,j);
       BFS(grids,i,j-1);
   }
};
```

Comment: how are `grid` and `grids` constructed?

Comment: `j>=grids[0].size()` would be safer as  `j>=grids[i].size()` because it is row `i` you'll access. (for the time someone will send you a non-rectangular vector of vector)

Comment: grids and grid are 2d vectors which are implemented in program . we just need to implement a function which returns number of islands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These three statements are in the wrong order

```
    int n=grid.size();
    int m=grid[0].size(); // <-- problem here
    if(grid.size()==0 || grid[0].size()==0)
        return 0;
```

it should be

```
    if(grid.size()==0 || grid[0].size()==0)
        return 0;
    int n=grid.size();
    int m=grid[0].size();
```

otherwise you get a crash accessing `grid[0]` when `grid.size()` equals zero.

Comment: but in the if(grid.size()==0);                                                                                                    it directly returns 0 it will not check grids[0].size()==0;                                                                 so can you explain me why if worked

Comment: @Doddigirish It will here `int m=grid[0].size();` You **alway**s do this assignment because you have the statements in the wrong order.

Comment: @Doddigirish I've added a comment to your code, to show where the problem is.